# Aws private/public vpc/nat gateway multiaz pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I am in doubt while creating my vpc in AWS. My goal is to have a multiAZ private network in regions A, B and C, but i am a little confused about the best way to create the public part and nat gateway for this network.

It is correct for me to create only one public network with one NATgatway to all my network or, since i have 3 availability zones, i should have 3 public networks and 3 NATgateways?

I guess i should make one NATgateway per network, but i would end up with 4 ou 6 route tables... Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multi-AZ pattern I use is to create a public and private subnet per AZ used.  Each public subnet will have its own NAT Gateway and each private subnet in that AZ will route through the corresponding public NAT AZ.

This image was taken from the ARC401.pdf reference below:

[image: Autoscale HA NAT]

This provides high availability.  If you lose an AZ the other AZ's will still function.  Having only one NAT gateway creates a single point of failure.

#### References

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/vpc/architecture.html
- http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/ARC401.pdf